# CloudFormation: conditional AutoScalingGroup notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, autoscaling

I want to receive AutoScaling Event notifications using SNS, but only in my PROD environment. How can I configure my CloudFormation template to do so?

Should it be like this:

```yaml
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: Environment of the application
    Type: String
    Default: dev
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - prod

Conditions:
  IsDev: !Equals [ !Ref Environment, dev]
  IsProd: !Equals [ !Ref Environment, prod]

Resources:
  mySNSTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties: 
      Subscription: 
        - Endpoint: "my@email.com"
          Protocol: "email"

  myProdAutoScalingGroupWithNotifications:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Condition: IsProd
    Properties:
      NotificationConfigurations:
        - NotificationTypes: 
            - "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR"
            - "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE"
            - "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR"
          TopicARN: !Ref "mySNSTopic"

  myDevAutoScalingGroupWithoutNotifications:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Condition: IsDev
    Properties:
```

Or does CloudFormation support the following too:

```yaml
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: Environment of the application
    Type: String
    Default: dev
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - prod

Conditions:
  IsProd: !Equals [ !Ref Environment, prod]

Resources:
  mySNSTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties: 
      Subscription: 
        - Endpoint: "my@email.com"
          Protocol: "email"

  myAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      NotificationConfigurations:
        - Condition: IsProd
          NotificationTypes: 
            - "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR"
            - "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE"
            - "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR"
          TopicARN: !Ref "mySNSTopic"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be double using [Fn::If](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) function:

```
  NotificationConfigurations:
    - !If 
        - IsProd
        - NotificationTypes: 
            - "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR"
            - "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE"
            - "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR"
          TopicARN: !Ref "mySNSTopic"          
        - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Can also try the following form:

```
  NotificationConfigurations:
    !If
      - IsProd
      - - NotificationTypes: 
            - "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR"
            - "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE"
            - "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR"
          TopicARN: !Ref "mySNSTopic"          
      - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Please be careful about indentation. You may need to adjust it to match your template.